# Aspose Library Tiff file format issue after .Net6 migration in linux environment

Tags: linux, .net-6.0, tiff, aspose

I am using aspose library to generate Tiff images. Here the problem is I am able to generate the file successfully, but the file is not loading properly, may be I guess fonts are missing
I have attached the screenshot below for ref.

Note: The issue occured in the linux server after .Net6 migration(Before .Net6 it's working fine)
[image]

Comment: Please, specify what Aspose library do you use, provide sample code and input files that will allow to reproduce the issue.

Comment: `public void ConvertHtmlToTif(Stream source, Stream estination,HtmlToTifConversionOptions options)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            stopwatch.Start();

            using (HTMLDocument doc = new HTMLDocument(source, ""))
            {
                CreateAndCropImageFromHtml(doc, destination, options);                
            }

            stopwatch.Stop();

            logger.Trace("Converted HTML to TIF in {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
        }`


Aspose.Html 22.10.01

Comment: We believe a similar topic has been created in our support forum where we have logged it in our issue tracking system for the sake of correction. You can please follow up there for the updates regarding issue resolution. (https://forum.aspose.com/t/tiff-file-format-issue-in-linux-server-after-net6-migration/255493)

Comment: I have posted the issue in the forum, still waiting for the replay, meanwhile if any one knows sln about the issue please let me know. 
Thanks advance.

Comment: We have posted a reply in the original forum thread with the updates related to the ticket.